# mvvm:How should i bind boolean value to combobox

Tags: mvvm

I am doing an application in MVVM and I am new at it...
I have a boolean field and want to show a combobox to user with items Yes/No but when user selects it,  but in data context values are 1 and 0.
i have the following code:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="Batch Flag" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                                <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="cboBtchFlg" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedADM_M022.BtchFlg,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Margin="5,0,0,2" Background="Transparent">
                                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="1">True</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="0">False</ComboBoxItem>
                                </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a converter. If the view model property is a bool, and this is bound to the SelectedIndex property of your combobox, which is an int, then this example will provide what you need.

```
public class IntToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // from view model to view
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            bool trueFalse = (bool)value;
            return trueFalse == true ? 0 : 1;
        }
        return value;
    }

    // from view to model
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            int index = (int)value;
            if (index == 0)
                return true;
            if (index == 1)
                return false;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Amend the SelectedIndex binding to

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedADM_M022.BtchFlg,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}"
```

given you have a resource called boolConverter that references your converter class e,g,

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IntToBoolConverter x:Key="boolConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```